# Theorem of S. Bernstein

Tags: real-analysis

I am reading a [paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1935-41-04/S0002-9904-1935-06049-5/S0002-9904-1935-06049-5.pdf) and on the last page it says:

By a well known
theorem of S. Bernstein, $\phi^{k_0}(x)$ is analytic for $a \leq x \leq b$ and consequently
$\phi(x)$ is analytic in the same interval.

Which theorem exactly is this?

Answer (score 1):

The assumption in use here is that all sufficiently high derivatives of $\phi$ are nonnegative. By replacing $\phi$ with the derivative $\phi^{(k)}$, we can say that *all* derivatives are nonnegative. Furthermore, flipping the sign of the independent variable makes our function [completely monotone](http://www.ma.utexas.edu/mediawiki/index.php/Completely_monotone_function).

The theorem of Bernstein (quoted on the page I linked) says that every completely monotone function is the Laplace transform of some measure. Consequently, it extends to a holomorphic function on a half-plane, and therefore must be real-analytic.